# Traducción de "polity"

Tags: traducción

¿Es `gobierno de la denominación` una traducción correcta para `Denominational polity`?

`Polity` se refiere a la estructura de gobierno eclesiástico.

> The General Synod shall have original authority over all matters pertaining to doctrine and **denominational polity** as they relate to the theological seminaries of the Reformed Church

Comment: ¿Tienes la frase en un poco más de contexto?  Creo que _jerarquía_ sería el término apropiado pero prefiero verlo en contexto.

Comment: La frase completa en inglés es "The General Synod shall have original authority over all matters pertaining to doctrine and denominational polity as they relate to the theological seminaries of the Reformed Church." Nuestro traductor tradujo como "El Sínodo General tendrá la autoridad sobre todos los asuntos relacionados con la doctrina y política de la denominación y su relación con los seminarios teológicos de la Iglesia Reformada". Creo que "política" significa "policy", que no es lo mismo que "polity". (También creo que "y su relación" debe ser "en su relación")

Comment: Una definición más precisa que mi original de "polity" sería las reglas de orden por la que funciona la iglesia; la autoridad y los deberes de varios niveles de gobierno en la iglesia.

Comment: What exact church is this? polity here means: gobierno o grupo constituído. denomination en inglés se refiere a las denominaciones cristianas o las denominaciones protestantes, p. ej. Aqui tienes la definición: https://www.ecured.cu/Denominaciones_cristianas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde luego la traducción realizada por *vuestro traductor* no parece muy acertada... La traducción que yo propongo para tu frase completa sería algo como:

> *El Sínodo General tendrá autoridad sobre todos los asuntos
>   relacionados con la doctrina y el régimen de gobierno confesional, puesto que
>   están relacionados con los seminarios teológicos de la Iglesia
>   Reformada.*

---

Si buscas [polity en WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=polity), verás lo siguiente:

[image]

Y si buscas [denominational en WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=denominational), verás lo siguiente:

[image]

Por lo tanto, la traducción propuesta, `política de la denominación`, no sólo ni se acerca a la traducción correcta, sino que además carece completamente de sentido...

La traducción de **polity** pienso que esta bastante clara...

En cuanto a la traducción de **denominational**, verás que una de las traducciones es ***denominacional***, que es una palabra que yo jamás habia oído, y que de hecho no esta recogida en el diccionario de la RAE. Yo supongo que se usa en América Latina, dónde quizás a veces existe cierta tendencia a *españolizar* de una forma demasiado directa las palabras inglesas...

Sin embargo, si buscas en el diccionario la última traducción, **[confesional](http://dle.rae.es/confesional)**, encontrarás que significa `perteneciente o relativo a una confesión religiosa`.

Por lo tanto, visto lo visto, parece que la traducción más correcta de `denominational polity` sería algo como:

> La estructura / forma / sistema de gobierno confesional / eclesiástico.

Lo cual, por cierto, se asemeja mucho a la traducción que propusiste en tu pregunta...

---

En cuanto a tu otra pregunta en el comentario, creo que cuando se dice `as they relate to`, se debería traducir por algo como:

> Puesto que/Ya que están relacionados/hacen referencia/guardan relación con ...

Comment: Lo que estoy buscando es una traducción de la frase inglés mencionada anteriormente que es mejor que la traducción proporcionada por el servicio de traducción (es un servicio profesional y remunerado, pero creo que no le confío.)

Comment: Sería suficiente decir "El Sínodo General tendrá la autoridad sobre todos los asuntos relacionados con la doctrina y el gobierno de la denominación ya que están relacionados con los seminarios teológicos de la Iglesia Reformada"?

Comment: @RCAEditor, tienes razón que he estado escribiendo un buen rato y al final no he dado la traducción, que es lo que a tí te interesaba... He añadido mi propuesta al principio de mi respuesta...

Comment: No creo que denominational sea confesinal o eclesiástico.